# At what point is requesting an image file faster than base64 encoding it inline?

Tags: html, image, browser, base64

I'm trying to come up with guidelines or performance testing that will help me choose which images to render inline as base64 encoded strings, and which should be requested as files from a cdn or similar.

Determining request time and delayed render is fairly straight forward in gauging the performance of the requested image, but I can't get a good read on render time for inlined images with the Chrome console. Obviously inline smaller images and request larger ones as a file, but what is a good cut off point?

For example, if an image is 2kb in size, and requesting it as a file it takes 100ms, how can I tell how long it takes to render the inline version of the same image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll always be faster rendering an inline base64 encoded string. A network request will always take longer than the CPU processing it takes to decode a base64 string. The question you should ask yourself is around the tradeoff of when you want to download the bytes: in the payload of the HTML or later in the payload of separate HTTP request. The more you add to the HTML, the longer your page load time will be. The benefit of downloading the image instead of inlining it is if you don't need it to display right away, you can defer it through an asynchronous fetch.

So ask yourself if it's more important to show the image ASAP or is it more important for the page to be ready to use sooner without the image? Same tradeoff discussion for inlining in CSS as well.

Comment: interesting, good answer! Does caching come into consideration here? i.e. I want to load a large image and using the browser cache with a sensibly set cache-control header might make it faster than re-rendering the inline version. I'm still unclear on if the rendering time is the same for either way of getting the image, and the request just adds extra time on top of that.

Comment: Good question. It might be different for each browser. I'd imagine reading the file's bytes and interpreting/rendering would be identical, so the question would be whether the cache overhead or base64 decoding takes longer.

Comment: Ah, so it's a comparison of fetch time vs. base64 decoding that is the deciding factor. That clarifies things for me.